# neo4J shortest path query via REST API doesn't return graph

Tags: neo4j

This query works fine in my neo4J browser

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((n1:FBDV)<-[:immediately_preceded_by*]-(n2:FBDV)) 
WHERE n1.label='embryonic stage 1' 
AND n2.label='embryonic stage 10' 
RETURN p
```

The JSON returned includes the a graph of the shortest path as well as a list of table rows (under data).

However, when run as a rest API query the JSON returned only includes the table data and no graph.

How can I get it to return the shortest path graph?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [transactional Cypher endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) you can specify that you'd like to receive results in both row and graph format:

`POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit`

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "MATCH p=shortestPath((n1:FBDV)<-[:immediately_preceded_by*]-(n2:FBDV)) WHERE n1.label='embryonic stage 1' and n2.label='embryonic stage 10' return p",
"resultDataContents" : [ "row", "graph" ]
  } ]
}
```

[This example](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) shows the format of the response.

Comment: Thx.  Works fine. Just what I needed.